# PHP consistent issue with no errors pertaining to code but also no expected output

Tags: php

as you may notice by the context of this text that I am a beginner learning php.  I have for the major part noticed that I am face with a interesting but  frustrating problem.  I consistently have no errors with the code but my expected output is not always echoed or displayed on the page.  Is this something that I need to pay attention to with respect to how I do things in PHP or has newbies seen this odd problem.  I constantly have to retrace the code and see what my mistakes are but there are no errors.  Thanks in advance!

---------function(s)----------

```
  function change_profile_image($user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn){

  $file_path = '$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/images/profile_images/' . substr(sha1(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file_extn;
  move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
  mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `profile` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($file_path) . "' WHERE `user_id` = " . (int)$user_id);

  }
```

---------profile php file -------

```
      $file_name = $_FILE['profile']['name'];
      $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
      $file_temp = $_FILE['profile']['tmp_name'];

      if(in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true){
         change_profile_image($session_user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn);
         header('Location:' .$current_file);
         exit();
      }else{
          $errors[] = 'Incorrect file type. Allow: ';
          echo implode(', ', $allowed);
      }
    }
  }
  if(empty($user_data['profile']) === false){
     echo '<image src="', $user_data['profile'],'" alt="', $user_data['first_name'], '\'s Profile Image">';
   }
   ?>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="profile"> <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Judging from the code you've supplied, I think the problem is that you've forgot to write a PHP script...

Comment: :). currently i am dealing with a tutorial that shows how to upload a file to "profile" page but I get no image upload and I get no errors.  I can show the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try switching on error reporting. 
let php display all the errors

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

use this snippet at the beginning of your php file.

alternatively, you can check your server logs to see if something gone wrong.

Comment: Hi Lucian,  Thanks for pointing that out.  I tried putting the suggested code at the top of my file and check it the upload process again but to no avail.  cheers!

Comment: ok, if the problem persists check your server logs to see what is happening on the server when you run your code.

Comment: Is there a way to mimic how the code will behave on my localhost and the live server 100%.  This I think might be my problem.  Although, I constantly transfer new changes to the server and test it if I don't get any output as expected on localhost.  I check the logs folder under my root directory on the server and it is all "Chinese" to me.  My apologies for the lack of better word.

Answer (score 0):

I Finally found my problem with the code.  I had a syntax error I should have have had $_FILES and NOT $FILE.  I was missing a "S" the entire time or bunch of "S"s .